# Non-cyclic polynomial with the cyclic permutations equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Consider $\:\: f(x,y,z) := \alpha^2(x-y) + \alpha(z-y)+ (x-z) \:\:$ with some constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \: \:$ If I'm not wrong, this function isn't cyclic. Now consider $$f(a,b,c) = f(c,a,b) = f(b,c,a) = 0 \:\:\: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Does this imply that $a=b=c$?

---

**Motivation**

On attempting the second problem from [this contest](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/rmo-2010) I employed the following approach $$P_1(\alpha) = P_2(\alpha) \implies \alpha^2(a-b)+\alpha(c-b)+(a-c) = 0 \tag 1  \:\:\:\:  \text{(I've omitted some simple algebra)}$$

Similarly we get $$\alpha^2(b-c) + \alpha(a-c) + (c-b) = 0 \tag 2$$ 
$$\alpha^2(c-a) + \alpha(b-a) + (c-b) = 0 \tag 3$$

After this we define $f(x,y,z)$ and if the property that I am thinking of is true, then I think we're done.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a proof for this.

$$(1) + (2) \implies \alpha^2(a-c) + \alpha(a-b) + (b-c) = 0 \tag #$$

$$(2) + (3) \implies \alpha^2(b-a) + \alpha(b-a) + \alpha(b-c) + (c-a) =0$$

Comparing coefficients we have $a-c = b-a$ implying that b,a,c are in arithmetic progression. Thus we replace the differences in # with a common difference $d$

$$\alpha^2(-d) + \alpha(d) -2d = 0 \implies d(-\alpha^2+ \alpha -2)=0$$

So either $d = 0$ or $-\alpha^2+ \alpha -2=0 $  but we know that $-\alpha^2+ \alpha -2 \neq 0$ since $\Delta <0$ and we know $\alpha$ to be real. Therefore $d=0$ and $a=b=c$

---

Alternatively $$(1) = (2) \implies a -b = b-c$$
Similarly we have $a-c = c-b$ and $a-c = b-a$

Therefore $a,b,c$ are all the middle term of the same arithemtic progression implying that the common difference is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for real $\alpha$ the only solutions are $a=b=c$.

The system of linear equations $f(a,b,c)=0, f(c,a,b)=0,f(b,c,a)=0$ has coefficient matrix
$$ A =  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\alpha}^{2}+1&-{\alpha}^{2}-\alpha&\alpha
-1\\ -{\alpha}^{2}-\alpha&\alpha-1&{\alpha}^{2}+1
\\ \alpha-1&{\alpha}^{2}+1&-{\alpha}^{2}-\alpha
\end {array} \right]
$$
which has rank $2$ (for generic values of $\alpha$) and null space spanned by $(1,1,1)^T$.  Thus for almost all $\alpha$, the only solutions have $a=b=c$.
To have other solutions, you'd need the rank to be at most $1$, which would require all $2 \times 2$ submatrices to have determinant $0$, i.e. all entries of the classical adjoint or [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) to be $0$.  In fact, all entries of the adjugate are 
$-{\alpha}^{4}-{\alpha}^{3}-2\,{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha-1$.  But this polynomial has no real roots.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what any of that means :P, but I guess I was right? Thanks anyway. By the way, is there an easier way to confirm my idea? Without going into anything too complicated? Furthermore is the idea simple enough to simply state without proof?

Comment: Another way is to compute the eigenvalues of $A$, which are $0$ and
$\pm \sqrt{3 \alpha^4 + 3 \alpha^3 + 6 \alpha^2 - 3 \alpha + 3}$.  Again it comes down to showing that $\alpha^4 + \alpha^3 + 2 \alpha^2 - \alpha + 1$ has no real roots.  And I **did** state that without proof.